# Only selected item's value is submitted

Tags: listview, gridview, dart, flutter

I have a ListView/GridView builder which has items generated from sqflite/SQLite database.

I want to select items from the list, and then submit value (string contained in each item) of only those items which are selected.

How can I achieve this?

I'll be grateful if you can give/refer me an example.

P.S. In case you are wondering, the submitted value (String) will be first displayed on a new screen, and then saved in a table of sqflite database.

Comment: Why don't you index each tile then update a separate hashmap?
Each tile has its own `setState`

Answer (score 0):

This codelab has items from a list being selected: [Write Your First Flutter App, part 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#5)

In step 6, we have `_saved` set being used. With that you can do something like:

```
List<String> selectedStrings = _saved.map((pair) => pair.asPascalCase).toList();
```

Now you can submit this list wherever. Perhaps you may concatenate them to a single `String`, if that makes things easier:

```
String concatenated = selectedStrings.join(",");
```